# How to access the variable out of scope of `if let` in swift

Tags: swift

I am new to swift that I would like to use the variable `funcReturn` out of `if let` scope. anyway better way for me to do it other than using `var` to declare the variable?

```swift
if let funcReturn = localFunction() {
    print(funcReturn)
}
print(funcReturn == "local function return value")

// i think I can do something like this but I do not need to change the value of funcReturn

if var funcReturn = localFunction() {
    print(funcReturn)
}
print(funcReturn == "local function return value")
```

Comment: If you are just using it for comparison, then you don't need to use the `if let` syntax. If you want to use the unwrapped value, then you should do it within the scope, there's no escaping the scope unless you create a variable outside the scope and modify it accordingly (which could remain unmodified when `if let` fails). Or else, you'll have to use `guard`, which does not fallthrough if `localFunction()` returns `nil`.

Comment: I cannot make sense of this. Please try harder to explain what you are asking; otherwise this question should be closed.

Comment: my code if more complicated than that and need to fall through all different condition check / reuse based on function return

Comment: @jacobcan118 Would be helpful if you could put more of your code here.

Comment: Your `if var` is not really different than an `if let`. It creates a new local var instead of a let. The var still only exists inside the braces of the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

`if let` and `if var` only define the new variable inside the braces that follow. That is the way the language works.

Consider this code:

```
func foo() {
    let aVar: Int? = 3
    if let bar = aVar {
       // bar is defined
    }
    // bar is not defined.
}
```

The same is true with an `if var`:

```
func foo() {
    let aVar: Int? = 3
    if var bar = aVar {
       // bar is defined
    }
    // bar is not defined.
}
```

(The compiler will tell you that your var was never mutated.) But at the "// bar is not defined." comment, the variable `bar` still won't exist.

As the other poster says, guard works the opposite way:

```
func foo() {
    let aVar: Int? = 3
    guard let bar = aVar  else {
        return
    }
    // bar is defined for the rest of the function.
}
```

`guard` requires that you leave the current scope if it fails. (Usually with a return, although you can also do other things like `break` or `continue` from an outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

The variable will only be in scope for the function. Another way to do it is a guard statement

Comment: i still can not access the variable like `guard let xxx = localFunction() else {}` my point is how can I use this `print(funcReturn == "local function return value")`?

Comment: You need more code to explain why `guard` isn’t your solution.